# Installing vim text editor on ubuntu

Tags: apt, vim

just installed LAMP server and need to use vim editor to edit php.ini

The command `sudo apt-get install vim` gives me the following error:

```
Package 'vim' is not available but is refered to by another package. This means the package is missing or is obsolete, or is only avaiable from another source.
E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate
```

Please advise

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Cannot install vim](http://askubuntu.com/q/78406/107450)

Answer (score 4):

Check your sources list `/etc/apt/sources.list` is as it should be. Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to download the package database. Then try again.

If all else fails, maybe you can find further advice and newer versions to compile from source on [www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org).

Answer (score 1):

Vim is a powerful editor and should install with the command you gave in 12.04, 12.10 or 13.04.

However you do not need **vim**.  There are other command line text editors available and I would suggest you use **nano** instead.  It is installed by default and while its not as powerful as vim it is much easier to learn.

If you have the desktop version of Ubuntu you can also use GUI based editors such as gedit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use vim. The text editor `nano` would have come in Ubuntu by default. Using it from the CLI is the same as vim:

```
nano /etc/path/to/php.ini
```

If you need vim itself, the `vim-nox` package should include vim:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-nox
```

The GUI version of Vim should also include command-line version of vim. You can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. the install of any of the vim packages does not occur :(

Comment: Could you show us the terminal output when you try to run the command? Also, which command is it?

Comment: The version of vim installed from `vim-gtk` has access to the xclipboard, while the version in `vim-nox` does not.

Answer (score 1):

If `vim` is not in the source.list of your system you can use usually `vi` too.

Check here for the difference: [What is the difference between Vi and Vim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418396/what-is-the-difference-between-vi-and-vim)

And you have always the option to compile it yourself, eg. http://www.vim.org/download.php#unix